# How to add UILabel on top of UIToolbar in iOS?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, uilabel

I added a label on top of the toolbar in iOS using a storyboard. 
It's showing on the storyboard but not on the simulator. I also added the auto-layout constraints. 
After running the application in simulator it's giving me some kind of exception.

[image: here is the picture: i want the label "Thought Share" on top of the tool bar.]

Comment: Update your question with details about the exception you are getting.

Comment: exception is gone, but still the label "Thought Share" is not showing in the simulator.

Comment: your constraints are not proper. One of possible problems.

Comment: what kind of constraints should i set to make this happen?. @MuhammadZohaibEhsan

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem after a very long debugging session -

- after setting up the toolbar, i set some layout constraints.
- then I add the label, with the same constraints

Both constraints are confliting that's why the label not showing on the toolbar.

Anyway thank you @Muhammad Zohaib Ehsan for your help.